# What would be a proper way of returning this promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, return, resolve

I'm new to coding and Promises are somewhat of an abstract concept for me. I know that in order to return a Promise you must use `.then` and `.catch` , but I'm unsure how exactly they should be used in the following code.

```
/**
 * Make an HTTPS request to the MTA GTFS API for a given feed.
 * @param  {String} baseUrl    - base URL for MTA GTFS API
 * @param  {String} feedId     - identifier for which realtime feed
 * @param  {String} apiKey     - key for MTA GTFS API
 * @return {<Object>}          - Promise of parsed feed.
 */

function makeRequest(baseUrl, feedId, apiKey) {
  const feedUrl = baseUrl + feedId;
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request(feedUrl,
      { headers: { 'x-api-key': apiKey } },
      (res) => {
        if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
          return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
        }
        var data;
        data = [];
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
          return data.push(chunk);
        });
        return res.on('end', function() {
          var msg;
          data = Buffer.concat(data);
          try {
            msg = nstrDecoder.decode(data);
          } catch (err) {
            try {
              console.log(err.message);
              msg = nsssDecoder.decode(data);
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err.message);
              msg = "";
            }
          }
          resolve(msg);
        });
      }
    );
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e.message);
    });
    req.end();
  });

}

return console.log(makeRequest(baseUrl, feedId, apiKey));
```

After running this code I get a message saying the Promise is pending. Thoughts??

Comment: Note that `console.log` always returns undefined.

Comment: Also `return data.push(...)` will return the new length of `data` after pushing the element into the array. There's a lot of uses of `return` in this code where I would not expect it. Remember the `return` will return a value to the function (arrow or not) that contains it. I'm not sure what `res.on()` returns, but I don't think the function passed to `request` will know what to do with it...

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function that returns a promise, you're going to get the promise in a pending state being it hasn't resolve or rejected yet. You have two options.

Option one.
node 10+ you can use async await.

```
async function main(){
const res = await makeRequest(baseUrl, feedId, apiKey)
return res
}
```

Pre node 10

```
makeRequest(baseUrl, feedId, apiKey)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Essentially if you have to wait for the data, you have to have the code that relies on that data after the await, or in the .then block.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

Your `makeRequest()` function returns a promise.  To use that promise, you use `.then()` or `await` to get the resolved value from the promise.

Using `.then()`:

```
makeRequest(baseUrl, feedId, apiKey).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

or using `await`:

```
async function someFunction() {
    try {
        let result = await makeRequest(baseUrl, feedId, apiKey);
        console.log(result);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

FYI, a lot of what `makeRequest()` is doing can be done simpler using an http request library that already supports promises.  There is a list of competent libraries to choose from [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).

My favorite is [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), but you can review the list to decide which one you like.  The main advantages are that they already collect the whole response for you, already support promises, support a wide variety of authentication schemes with built-in logic and can often decode or parse the response for you - all things which `https.request()` does not know how to do by itself.